# Change the exit button style on Fluent UI's Panel

Tags: office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

I'm using Panel from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Panel' in React.

This Panel generates a little [x] button on the upper right hand corner. It is very hard to see, is there any way to change its default background color to red & modify its mouse hover value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily change the `button style` through `styles` property of *Panel Component*:

```
styles={{
   closeButton: {
     backgroundColor: '#f00',
   },
}}
```

If you want to change the `hover style` of `button`, you have to use `selectors` property:

```
styles={{
   closeButton: {
     backgroundColor: '#f00',
     selectors: {
       ':hover': {
         backgroundColor: '#000'
       },
     },
   },
}}
```

Panel Component:

```
<Panel
  styles={{
    closeButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#f00',
      selectors: {
        ':hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#000'
        },
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

Working [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/dyXNaRY?editors=0010)

**Useful links:**

- Definition of [Panel Component styles](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/cbc0b9a2f9b569eeabd7bba3812002edcca948e8/packages/react-internal/src/components/Panel/Panel.styles.ts#L23)
- And this one is the most important [Component Styling](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling)